# A User can be a Teacher or a Admin, or a Parent, or a Student. How to achieve this using Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table called User. And there are other tables Admin, Teacher, Parent and Student. Now, a User can be a Teacher or a Admin, or a Parent, or a Student. How to implement this using Django models?

Comment: Please paste in the tables (models). There are multiple ways to do this kind of thing, so it is very helpful to see what you have already done. Also, are these 4 groups exclusive - i.e., every user is exactly one of Teacher/Admin/Parent/Student - or can a user be in multiple groups.

Comment: I am looking for below cases. 1. User can take exactly one of the four roles. 2. User can take more than one role.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Django's generic relations and content types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1). Assuming the relation of User to Teacher/Admin/Parent/Student is called "role", below is pseudocode of what that should look like:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="role")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Something like this would be preferable:

##### Situation 1:

- If the user can only handle one role, you can employ the below:

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_ROLES = (
        ('A', 'Administrator'),
        ('T', 'Teacher'),
        ('S', 'Student'),
        ('P', 'Parent'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False, choices=USER_ROLES )
    # ... other fields here...

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.get_full_name())


class Administrator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ... other fields here...

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ... other fields here...

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ... other fields here...

class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ... other fields here...
```

##### Situation 2:

- If the user needs more than one role, you can employ the below:

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    is_administrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # ... other fields here...

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.get_full_name())
```